# how to avoid content type hub to replace my local libraries document templates? (SharePoint 2013)

Tags: 2013, content-type, content-type-hub

In some specific web libraries, I need to set specific document templates on list content types. My problem is that if I republish the parent content type from the hub, my local templates are replaced by their parent refreshed one.

In the content type hub, I can update the parent content type, specifying I do not want the children to be updated. Unfortunately, it seems I do not have the choice in the site collections consumers...